# Micro Service Architecute - Independent server service or on same server?

Tags: amazon-web-services, microservices

I am designing the architecture for software. I am in process of creating micro services related to big component.

Either i can create micro service on different server or on same server. Is it good to create micro service component on same server instance or i can create different micro-services on diffrent server.

I think its good too have different server for bigger components, obviously it will increase the cost. 
Can any one please let me know your thoughts  on this.
Thanks

Comment: While using either option (same or different server) would still give you logically separate microservices, best practice would probably say that each microservice should run on its own machine.  This is to ensure that if one server goes done, it does not take down the entire system.

Comment: Yes, the services are logically separate and the part which is not separate having a fallback for extreme conditions.

Comment: IMHO this is where docker shines. Have you considered packaging your services as container images. That would enable you to efficiently use resources with the help of an orchestrator like ECS or EKS. Also even though ECS Fargate is slightly expensive than the vanilla ECS, you don't have to worry about provisioning underlying machines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend a combined approach; Services are containerized in a shared server, this provides some level of isolation between the services. While using multiple servers for increasing availability and horizontally scaling.

From my experience this achieves the lowest cost and highest availability.

A good container orchestration system like Kubernetes abstracts this and combines all servers in a one virtual cluster, which simplifies the management of the whole infrastructure. In addition it provides some useful services that benefits this type of architecture, like managing the lifecycle of individual services, load balancing and moving services between nodes in case of hardware failure.